# Why "document.getElementById("lessonSelect").addEventListener" does not work?

Tags: javascript

Ok, in `.js` file

```
....
document.getElementById("lessonSelect").addEventListener("load", getAllLessonNos());
....
```

In `html file`,

```
<button onclick="getAllLessonNos()">Show All Lessons</button>
<select id="lessonSelect"> </select>
```

Nothing happened after the page is loaded, that is the function  `getAllLessonNos()` has not been called.

However, when I click the button "Show All Lessons", it will show all lessons without any problems.

[This webpage](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) say we can do "`object.addEventListener("load", myScript);`"

So, what is wrong?

Comment: *This webpage say we can do "object.addEventListener("load", myScript);"* … but you are doing `myScript()` not `myScript`.

Comment: `<select>` elements don't have load events either.